# How to prove CDF $F(x)$ exists or is unique?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions

$$h(x) = \int_{x}^{a} g(y)(F(y)-F(x))^{N-1}F(dy) $$
Where $F(\cdot)$ is the CDF of interest. Constants $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and functions $h(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ are continuous, bounded and infinitely differentiable.

Really stuck on this, so any information on how to show uniqueness or solubility will be very helpful, even if it isn't a complete proof.

Comment: I guess the question is:  "Given the data $a,N,h,g$, does there exist $F$ satisfying this equation for all $x$, and is it unique?"  This question is likely to be closed unless you show more information.  For example, can you do a simple case.  Say $N=1, a=0, g(x) = 1$, can you obtain an arbitrary $h$?  If so, try more general cases.